# How to reuse a Chartjs Chart component in with different Data and get past the **Canvas is already in use** error?

Tags: vue.js, canvas, chart.js, vue-chartjs, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a boxplot component in my Vue project and I want to reuse it on the same page for a table I am building.

[image]

However, despite the fact that my data is different, I still get this `Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused.` error.

I've seen this question asked previously on here, but none of the threads 'fixes' really helped me here. ([Threads I've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69516326/canvas-is-already-in-use-chart-with-id-0-must-be-destroyed-before-the-canvas) and [video I tried to replicate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvkT6a17L2s)).

Since I have no idea of how many rows (and charts) I will need to use, I don't think [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69559728/eror-chart-min-js13-uncaught-in-promise-error-canvas-is-already-in-use-cha) is very practical. Is there anyway around this type of error?

Do I need a new id generated for each chart I am using? Since this is utilizing the basic Chartjs library and not the normal [VueChart3 syntax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chart-3) I've been using throughout the rest of my app, I am a bit stumped.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

[**CodeSandbox Link**](https://codesandbox.io/s/boxplot-in-a-table-nyi0o0?file=/src/components/boxplot-mock-data.js)

**BoxPlotChart.vue**

```
<template>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from "vue";
import { Chart, registerables } from "chart.js";
import { BoxPlotChart } from "@sgratzl/chartjs-chart-boxplot";
Chart.register(...registerables);
export default defineComponent({
  name: "CBoxPlotChart",
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
    width: {
      type: String,
      // default: '400px'
    },
    height: {
      type: String,
      // default: '300px'
    },
    showLegend: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    onMounted(() => {
      // @ts-ignore
      const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart")?.getContext("2d");
      ctx.canvas.parentNode.style.width = `${props.width}px`;
      ctx.canvas.parentNode.style.height = `${props.height}px`;
      if (!ctx) return;
      const myChart = new BoxPlotChart(ctx, {
        // type: 'boxplot',
        // @ts-ignore
        data: props.data,
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          indexAxis: "y",
          // @ts-ignore
          clip: false,
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Chart.js Box Plot Chart",
          },
          plugins: {
            datalabels: {
              display: false,
            },
            legend: {
              display: false,
            },
            tooltip: {
              // if you want to hide the tooltip, just uncomment the line below
              // enabled: false,
              displayColors: false,
              bodyFont: {
                size: 12,
                family: "Inter",
              },
              bodyColor: "#4771FA",
              backgroundColor: "white",
              callbacks: {
                title: () => "",
                label: (context) => {
                  console.log(`context!`, context.parsed.max);
                  const mean = context.parsed.mean.toFixed(3);
                  const q1 = context.parsed.q1.toFixed(3);
                  const q3 = context.parsed.q3.toFixed(3);
                  const boxplotValues = [
                    `Q3: ${q3}`,
                    `Mean: ${mean}`,
                    `Q1: ${q1}`,
                  ];
                  return boxplotValues;
                },
              },
            },
          },
          layout: {
            padding: {
              left: 10,
              right: 5,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 10,
            },
          },
          scales: {
            x: {
              display: false,
            },
            y: {
              display: false,
            },
          },
        },
      });
    });
    return {
      // isResponsive,
      // getData,
      // options,
      // barChartProps,
      // myStyles,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

**Table.vue**

```
<template>
  <table class="no-spacing" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Chart</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="margin: 0.5rem">05/03/22</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div
          style="
            background: #FFE2E2;
            padding: 1rem;
            margin: 0.5rem;
            border-radius: 8px;
          "
        >
          12.93
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: max-content">
        <BoxPlotChart :data="boxplotData" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="margin: 0.5rem">05/03/22</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div
          style="
            background: #FFE2E2;
            padding: 1rem;
            margin: 0.5rem;
            border-radius: 8px;
          "
        >
          12.93
        </div>
      </td>
      <!-- <td style="width: max-content">
        <BoxPlotChart :data="boxplotData2" />
      </td> -->
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import BoxPlotChart from "./BoxPlotChart.vue";
import { boxplotData, boxplotData2 } from "./boxplot-mock-data";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "",
  props: {},
  emits: [],
  components: { BoxPlotChart },
  setup() {
    return { boxplotData, boxplotData2 };
  },
});
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
table
  th
    text-align: center
  tr, td
    border: 1px solid #DCE5FA
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's in web design should be unique. At the moment each time you create a new `BoxPlotChart` component it adds a canvas with id `'myChart'` to the DOM.

You either have to generate a random ID within your `BoxPlotChart` chart component or pass along an ID in the props which you give to the canvas

Comment: Thank you for your comment again! Interesting, I never thought of that. The issue I am currently having though is the `const myChart = new BoxPlotChart()` section. I've updated my example to try and pass and `id` prop, but to no avail. Do you have any ideas on what you would need to do with that `const myChart`? Updated codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/boxplot-in-a-table-multiple-rows-nyi0o0?file=/src/components/BoxPlotChart.vue

Comment: You didn't pass the id prop to the canvas, you setted the id to `id`, you need to use `v-bind` to dynamically add the id, also you need an wrapping div around the canvas otherwise it will expand permanently.

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/boxplot-in-a-table-multiple-rows-forked-m4u9t2

Comment: Thank you so much for the help here! This is perfect